# How to read a radio stream by php and stream it out again

Tags: php, mp3, php-curl

I´m trying to get data from a radio stream (MP3) from http and want to stream it out in https.
this is what I tried:

```
<?php

define(URL, 'Mymp3stream.com');

$ch = curl_init(URL);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
  CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE
));

curl_exec($ch);
```

how can I get it streamed ?
the browser doesn´t start any audio output.
Even with Headers

```
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

there was no audio in the browser.
the page is loading all the time.

I also tried to read the stream into a string buffer and echoed it out with:

```
$stream=fopen($url, 'rb');
 while(!feof($stream)){
   $buffer=fread($stream, 128);
   echo $buffer;
   flush();
 }
fclose($stream);
```

another try was to use get_stream_content after opening the file with fopen.
there was a minor success after adding the headers:
In Chrome there was showed the audioplayer, but no sound started to play.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @phil1283 I suggest you delete this question and repost what you've got up there. I've done this with PHP but cannot Answer if your question is on hold.

Comment: @VC.One I set pu a new question and will then delete this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961486/php-how-to-stream-a-mp3-stream-again

Comment: @phil1283 okay i've seen the other one & will answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this option :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

The curl_exec will return the result as array as explain in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-exec.php)