# PHP how to stream a mp3 stream again

Tags: php, curl, mp3

I´m trying to get data from a radio stream (MP3) from http and want to stream it out in https.
this is what I tried:

```
<?php

define(URL, 'Mymp3stream.com');

$ch = curl_init(URL);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
  CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE
));

curl_exec($ch);
```

how can I get it streamed ?
the browser doesn´t start any audio output.
Even with Headers

```
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

there was no audio in the browser.
the page is loading all the time.

I also tried to read the stream into a string buffer and echoed it out with:

```
$stream=fopen($url, 'rb');
 while(!feof($stream)){
   $buffer=fread($stream, 128);
   echo $buffer;
   flush();
 }
fclose($stream);
```

another try was to use get_stream_content after opening the file with fopen.
there was a minor success after adding the headers:
In Chrome there was showed the audioplayer, but no sound started to play.

Comment: PS: Do you have a link to `Mymp3stream.com` for checking? I just saw my method involves knowing the url of mp3 data being served (can try find out for you). I used PHP for proxying to achieve visualisation of the radio stream.

Comment: @VC.One: thanks for help here is a sample stream of our local radio station: http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de:80/antenne

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

For your stream, using PHP's `readfile();` is enough. It achieves same result as putting the radio link directly in an `<audio>` tag.

**PHP** code (save as `testproxy.php`) :

```
<?php

$file = "http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/antenne";
readfile($file);

?>
```

**HTML** (use the above PHP file as source of some `<audio>` tag) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="audio" controls>
  <source crossorigin="anonymous" src="testproxy.php" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your approach, does it work on your System? I tried it on two different pc with internet explorer and chrome. both are loading to infinity. Any idea? Has the buffersize to be declared in the php file?